# iAd Banner View Delegate Not Calling Methods

Tags: objective-c, ios, iad

I have an iAd banner view, with all my contracts up and running, and I've implemented the `ADBannerView` delegate.  The banner should disappear with no internet connection, but it just shows a white box where the content should be.  I know I have all the code right, I've seen a million tutorials on this.  So I ran some tests and found that the banner view wasn't even calling the two methods for the delegate!  Here is the code.

In the .h file:

```
#import <iAd/iAd.h>

@interface DetailViewController : ADBannerViewDelegate>
{
    ADBannerView *aBanner;
    BOOL bannerIsVisible;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet ADBannerView *aBanner;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL bannerIsVisible;

@end
```

in the .m file:

```
@implementation DetailViewController

@synthesize aBanner,bannerIsVisible;

//Show banner if can load ad.
-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
      { 
         if (!self.bannerIsVisible) { 
            [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOn" context:NULL]; banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, -banner.frame.size.height); 
            [UIView commitAnimations]; self.bannerIsVisible = YES; }
      }

    //Hide banner if can't load ad.
    -(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
    { 
        if (self.bannerIsVisible) { 
            [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOff" context:NULL]; banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, banner.frame.size.height);           
            [UIView commitAnimations]; self.bannerIsVisible = NO; }
    }
```

Comment: Do the delegate methods get called when there's a working connection?

Comment: One gets called when there is connection, one when there isn't

Comment: Right, I understand what the methods mean. What I'm asking is, does your code work when there's a connection? They may not work at all, regardless of the connection.

Comment: That was  my question.  I noticed that even without connection, neither of the methods were getting called

Comment: Do you ever set your view controller as the ad banner view's delegate?

Comment: That is my view controller.  It's not a `UIViewController` preset in Xcode, but a subclass of it.

Comment: Yes, but just implementing the ADBannerViewDelegate protocol isn't enough. You also need to set the controller as the delegate. Probably with something like `self.aBanner.delegate = self;`

Comment: isn't that in the `viewDidLoad` method?

Comment: That's where I would put it. Is it there?

Comment: I did put it there once, but I got the same results as when I didn't.

Comment: You probably need to add that back. Also, make sure that `self.aBanner` is not `nil`.

Comment: It still didn't change anything.

Answer (score 3):

You have to set the banner delegate to files owner. I had the same issue and after beating my head against the wall it was that simple.

Comment: i have set delegate to filesowner but bannerViewDidLoadAd not call.

Answer (score 0):

Use the code shown below to declare your own delegate

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
  aBanner.delegate = self;
}
```